# Can I update multiple columns of table by query language using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I created one table like student and I fetched the address based on age (like age = 22). Now I want to update the address based on age "22" to all address columns of table. How can I do this?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "demoJPA").createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT student FROM Student student WHERE student.age = 22");
    System.out.println("Data is" + query.getResultList().size());
    List<Simpletable> simpletable = query.getResultList();

    for (Simpletable simpletable1 : simpletable){
         System.out.println(simpletable1.getAddress());
    }
}
```

I fetched data but how can I update now. Is it possible to iterate through a loop and setAddress("US")

Comment: @MEssaBaloch stop suggesting invalid edits. You make the formatting **worse**. Read about the term [indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating a standalone application, you must open a transaction first, then you can simply change the field values in your object and when the transaction is committed, the changes get flushed to the database automatically.

```
EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
try {
   tx.begin();
   try {
      for(SimpleTable simpleTable : simpleTables){
         simplaTable.setAddress(newAddress);
      }
   } finally {
      tx.commit();
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   // handle exceptions from transaction methods
}
```

--Edit--

An alternative to edit all records without having to first fetch them is to do a bulk update, still within a transaction, like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE SimpleTable s " +
               "SET s.address.state = ?1 " +
               "WHERE s.address.country = ?2")
  .setParameter(1, "FL")
  .setParameter(2, "US")
  .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I am loading entire data from table. Then how can I set the address to all students. without using any ID value

Comment: And Based on your code I did, but I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.jpa.demo.entities.Simpletable exception Thank you very much

Comment: @codegeek I have updated the answer to address your question. Also my code are examples of how to do it. You have to adapt them to your own scenario. I don't know the details of your code, only you do, so my examples are not for copying and pasting and then expect they would work. They are guides on what you could try.

Comment: Is it possible to update data without query. I mean while inserting data we use setAddress("") like this right. Now I want in same scenario without using update query language to update address into table.

Comment: Based on condition we get list of Address from Table.In our program you did like UPDATE SimpleTable SET s.address.state = ?1 . Instated of writing UPDATE query is it possible to update the address like setAddress("LA").

Comment: @codegeek I already show you how to do that in the first example of the two that I wrote. Am I missing something here?